# Worldclim past data retrieval using R

Tags: raster, r

Here is how I can retrieve current and future data using the raster package:

Current environment from worldclim

```r
current=getData("worldclim", var="bio", res=2.5)

Future env
future=getData('CMIP5', var='bio', res=2.5, rcp=85, model='HE', year=70) names(futureEnv)=names(currentEnv)
```

How do I retrieve past LGM environment data from worldclim using an enhancement to the above script?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find out how to download those past data layers through R? I would love to know this answer as well.